# Probability problem, a variant of the birthday problem

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins, birthday

There are $m$ bins and $n$ identical balls. We randomly (uniformly) throw the balls to the bins. Then we count the number of bins which only have 1 ball in it. What is the probability that this number is bigger than $t$, $(0 \leq  t < m)$?

Comment: what makes you suggest this is a variant of the birthday paradox?

Comment: The probability of having at least one bin having more than one ball in it is the birthday problem.

Comment: So can you edit your question with what have you tried, as you know what the birthday problem is doing?

Comment: How would it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of combinations with exactly $k$ bins being occupied with a single ball is:
$$\begin{align}
N_k&=\binom nk \binom mk k!\sum_{i\ge0}(-1)^i\binom{n-k}i\binom{m-k}i i!(n-k-i)^{m-k-i}\\
&=\frac{ n! m!}{k!}\sum_{i\ge0}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\frac{(n-k-i)^{m-k-i}}{(n-k-i)!(m-k-i)!},
\end{align}
$$
where $\binom nk$ and $\binom mk k!=\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}$ stay for the numbers of ways to choose $k$ bins to be occupied with a single ball and to place $k$ (distinguishable) balls into these bins, respectively. The following sum counts the number of ways to place the rest $m-k$ balls into $n-k$ bins with exclusion of the cases of a single ball placed in one of these bins (inclusion-exclusion principle). The factors $\binom{n-k}i$ and $\binom{m-k}i i!$ have here the same origin as discussed above.

Finally the probability in question is:
$$
p_t=\frac1{n^m}\sum_{k>t} N_k.
$$

Comment: Smart solution. Thank you!

Comment: @zubizerreta But obviously something prevents you to accept it. I would be happy to know how the answer can be improved.

Comment: I am sorry I am new here. Your solution is clear.

Comment: @Zubizerreta No problem. We all were unexperienced with the engine. You are welcome!